# passing the arguments of a function as the key of an object threw brackets to change it's value

Tags: javascript, function, object, brackets

I have 2 files.
DB.json, app.js.

DB.json :

```
{
  "val": 5,
  "square": 25,
  "add": null,
}
```

What i want to do is to calculate addFct and then use writeFct in order to write the value into DB.js

```
async function add(x){
  let val = await square(val)
  return val + x
}

async function writefct(fct,y){
 
  userDBupdate[fct] = await fct(y)
  let dataMAJ = JSON.stringify(userDBupdate)
  fs.writeFileSync(dbPath, dataMAJ)
}
writefct(add,1)
```

My DB.json creat a new key instead of rewrite value of the key "add"
If i try to convert fct argument to string i obtain a new key "[object Undefined]"
If i use dot notation.... a new key named as the argument "fct" not "add" as the name of the function

Comment: Maybe `userDBupdate[fct.name] = await fct(y)` ? Of course that only works as long as you are not using a minifier that changes function names.

Comment: Yeah thank you, that's the solution. I forgot that we could access the name of a function this way ! Noob's life is hard

Answer (score 3):

At line `userDBupdate[fct] = await fct(y)` fct is a function.

When any `object type` values are used as an object key, It will use the [Object ...] as a key

If any function is called toString it returns a string representing the source code of the function.

Here you need the name of the referenced function so,

To set name of the function that was passed - to be the key, You can use `fct.name`

Comment: That's it ! I forgot that we could access the name of a function this way ! Noob's life is hard